# Merge rows postgres and replace values with latest when not null

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I am looking for a way to merge the columns on `organizations_core_id` so that the query returns this:

```
organization_core_id, slug, name
1, dolphin, Dolphin v2
2, sea-horse-club, Sea Horse
```

How can I merge these columns and replace the latest value?

Comment: What is the logic behind this merge?

Comment: @forpas consolidate rows based on `organizations_core_id` and get the latest non-null columns for that `organizations_core_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `group by organization_core_id` to get the ids of the rows with the last not null values for `slug` and `name` and then join to the table:

```
select
  t.organization_core_id, 
  t1.slug,
  t2.name
from (
  select 
    organization_core_id, 
    max(case when slug is not null then id end) slugid, 
    max(case when name is not null then id end) nameid
  from tablename
  group by organization_core_id
) t 
left join tablename t1 on t1.id = t.slugid
left join tablename t2 on t2.id = t.nameid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=fad4fde978a877d3d5614def34306787).
Results:

```
> organization_core_id | slug           | name      
> -------------------: | :------------- | :---------
>                    1 | dolphin        | Dolphin v2
>                    2 | sea-horse-club | Sea Horse
```