# Merge rows in PostgreSQL and replace values with latest when not null, but join on other column

Tags: postgresql

My question is 90% the same as the one below, but with a twist that makes it a bit more complicated:
[Merge rows postgres and replace values with latest when not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818097/merge-rows-postgres-and-replace-values-with-latest-when-not-null)

The difference is that in the original question the `max(case when slug is not null then id end) slugid` was also what should be joined on, but for me the join should happen based on the value of *another column*.

Example `documents` table (`contracts` to `documents` is a 1:many relationship):

| id | contract_id | timestamp | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UUID-C | UUID-A | 2021-08-18 10:00 | X | Y | Z |
| UUID-D | UUID-A | 2021-08-18 11:00 | null | F | null |
| UUID-E | UUID-B | 2021-08-18 11:00 | F | null | null |
| UUID-F | UUID-B | 2021-08-18 12:00 | null | G | null |
| UUID-G | UUID-B | 2021-08-18 13:00 | X | null | H |

Expected result:

| contract_id | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UUID-A | X | F | Z |
| UUID-B | X | G | H |

The `documents` column that should be used for determining the most recent (and therefore, most important) row is `timestamp`, but the `documents.id` should be used for merging the results instead of the timestamp in order to prevent unexpected behaviour.

An example of how the most recent timestamps are selected for each `a`, `b`, `c` value is this:

```sql
SELECT
    contract_id,
    max(case when a is not null then timestamp end) a_timestamp,
    max(case when b is not null then timestamp end) b_timestamp,
    max(case when c is not null then timestamp end) c_timestamp,
    FROM documents
    GROUP BY contract_id;
```

but then the join should happen based on `id`, not on `timestamp`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be much simpler than expected, no joins are required at all when solving it like this:

```sql
SELECT c.id,
    (SELECT a FROM documents d WHERE d.a IS NOT NULL AND d.contract_id = c.id ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) as a,
    (SELECT b FROM documents d WHERE d.b IS NOT NULL AND d.contract_id = c.id ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) as b,
    (SELECT c FROM documents d WHERE d.c IS NOT NULL AND d.contract_id = c.id ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) as c,
FROM contracts c;
```

In reality, there are not 3 (abc) but 10 (abcdefghij) fields. If someone knows a way to write this query more elegantly without repeating the same line 10 times, then please tell me in a comment :-).

Answer (score 1):

After a few false starts I came up with this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION coalesce2(anyelement,anyelement) RETURNS anyelement
      LANGUAGE sql AS 'select coalesce($1,$2)' ;
CREATE AGGREGATE firstval_agg(anyelement)
      (sfunc=coalesce2,stype=anyelement);

SELECT DISTINCT ON ( contract_id ) 
  contract_id 
  ,firstval_agg(a) OVER w AS timestamp_a
  ,firstval_agg(b) OVER w AS timestamp_b
  ,firstval_agg(c) OVER w AS timestamp_c
FROM documents 
WINDOW w AS (partition by contract_id order by timestamp DESC)
ORDER BY contract_id ,timestamp;
```

The `,firstval_agg(a) OVER w AS timestamp_a` part and `WINDOW w AS`... part collect the desired values on the first row of each group

the `DISTINCT ON ( contract_id )` and `ORDER BY`... causes it to return only the first row of each group.

result:

```
 contract_id | timestamp_a | timestamp_b | timestamp_c 
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------
 UUID-A      | X           | F           | Z
 UUID-B      | X           | G           | H
```